# supervisor.conf default location

Tags: python, deployment, configuration, supervisord

Im trying to make automatic deployment including supervisord and confused by default settings path.

Every deployment scheme I found use `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` and `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` without any presettings and links, also, after installing supervisor package via apt-get this path is really filled by example configuration.

In this [example](https://github.com/samuelclay/NewsBlur/blob/master/fabfile.py) flow looks like this without any links and creation anything like `/etc/supervisor.conf`:

```
sudo('apt-get -y install supervisor')
put('config/supervisor_gunicorn.conf', '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf', use_sudo=True)
sudo('supervisorctl reload')
```

But in `supervisorctl` this path is not specified as default and it's assumed that default location somewhere aroud `/etc/supervisor.conf` so as specified in [manual](http://supervisord.org/installing.html)

I've try to install supervisor all possible ways but I can't get result.

I know that this is just small stupid detail, but I will be very grateful for your assistance in keeping my deployment scheme good.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Normally* the default file is indeed `/etc/supervisor.conf`, but the [Debian distribution patches this](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/supervisor/supervisor_3.0a8-1.1.diff.gz) (link to the gzipped patch as provided by Debian) to look for `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` first:

```
--- supervisor-3.0a8.orig/src/supervisor/options.py
+++ supervisor-3.0a8/src/supervisor/options.py
@@ -105,7 +105,7 @@
     def default_configfile(self):
         """Return the name of the found config file or raise. """
         paths = ['supervisord.conf', 'etc/supervisord.conf',
-                 '/etc/supervisord.conf']
+                 '/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf', '/etc/supervisord.conf']
         config = None
         for path in paths:
             if os.path.exists(path):
```

So with that patch, supervisor looks for `supervisord.conf` in the local directory, in the `etc/` subdirectory, then in the global `/etc/supervisor/` and `/etc/` directories.

The default `supervisord.conf` file installed by Debian has this at the end:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

causing supervisord to load any extra files put in the `conf.d` directory.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I revised what the package installation changing on my server, so reason was that it is installing partially (maybe pythonbrew is the reason maybe something else) and the patch is not applying.

Comment: Nice find. I was wondering how the ubuntu version was looking for /etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf.

Comment: This was so useful for me when rewriting a Dockerfile to use Alpine instead of Debian Jessie. All I did was add `RUN printf "\n[include]\nfiles = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf\n" >> /etc/supervisord.conf` to my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 9):

You may have installed supervisor via pip and therefore have the unpatched version  in

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/`

taking precedance over the patched version in

`/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor`

See Martjin's answer for details on the patch. The simple solution is to:

`pip uninstall supervisor`

Then rerun the package install in case it was only partially installed:

`apt-get install supervisor`

Also make sure your `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` is present. If not, you may need to manually recreate it, mine looks like this:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run//supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run//supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on centos. Do I need to change supervisorctl config?

Answer (score 0):

From ze actual documentation: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#configuration-file

> The Supervisor configuration file is conventionally named
>   supervisord.conf. It is used by both supervisord and supervisorctl. If
>   either application is started without the -c option (the option which
>   is used to tell the application the configuration filename
>   explicitly), the application will look for a file named
>   supervisord.conf within the following locations, in the specified
>   order. It will use the first file it finds.
>
> 1. $CWD/supervisord.conf
> 2. $CWD/etc/supervisord.conf
> 3. /etc/supervisord.conf
> 4. /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (since Supervisor 3.3.0)
> 5. ../etc/supervisord.conf (Relative to the executable)
> 6. ../supervisord.conf (Relative to the executable)

Answer (score 0):

These all are default configuration file pathes.

- /usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf
- /usr/local/supervisord.conf
- supervisord.conf
- etc/supervisord.conf
- /etc/supervisord.conf
- /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf