# Run supervisor in virtual environment

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord

I installed `supervisor` and `gunicorn` in my virtual environment (`venv`).

I am using this tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/

I'm confused as to where I should be creating the `config` file for `supervisor` as the default `etc/supervisor` won't apply to me.

The `supervisorctl` file is in the directory:

**/home/giri/venv/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor**

I noticed this line in the `supervisorctl` file:

```
Options:
-c/--configuration -- configuration file path (default /etc/supervisord.conf)
```

Do I need to manually set this flag each time I run the `supervisorctl` script or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [supervisor.conf default location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226113/supervisor-conf-default-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found in the docs (http://supervisord.org/configuration.html):

> The Supervisor configuration file is conventionally named
>   supervisord.conf. It is used by both supervisord and supervisorctl. If
>   either application is started without the -c option (the option which
>   is used to tell the application the configuration filename
>   explicitly), the application will look for a file named
>   supervisord.conf within the following locations, in the specified
>   order. It will use the first file it finds.
>
> - $CWD/supervisord.conf
> - $CWD/etc/supervisord.conf
> - /etc/supervisord.conf

So put the `supervisor.conf` in your current working directory and you're fine.